# Set min time in TimePickerAndroid react native

Tags: react-native, timepicker

I want to set 5:00 PM as min time in `TimePickerAndroid`. How can I set it?

```
this.showPicker.bind(this, 'simple', {
         hour: new Date().getHours(),
         minute: new Date().getMinutes(),
         minHour: this.props.minHour // I am passing 5 as minHour prop
})
```

I tried this but didn't work.

Comment: What you mean by min time? Do you want the picker to display 5 pm initially

Comment: No if I set minTime 5 PM then user can only select time greater than 5 PM

Comment: Its answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826076/set-min-and-max-date-on-react-day-picker

Answer (score 0):

[This library](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker) helps solve the issue but as the `timepickerandroid api` in `react-native` doesn't have the `min & max time properties`, hence the `min & max time properties` can only be set for `ios` and not for `android`

You can use [this property](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker/issues/156) to set `min & max times` but it will work **only** for `ios`

Comment: That library is not properly documented. I am unable to find the way to deal with time picker with that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, for the react-native-datepicker, minDate is not supported for the Android. It works fine for ios.

I followed the method below to overcome the issue in android.

source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58400641/9366229

Hope it will help!!

Comment: Linked resource can be deleted. It is preferable to describe solutions direct on SO.