# Set min and max date on react day picker

Tags: datepicker, react-day-picker, react-datepicker

How do i set maximum or minimum date? 
Like for instance, i want to limit my daypicker only for the last 2 month (min date) until today (max date). So the user can't choose tomorrow's date. Thanks

http://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/

Answer (score 12):

You need to use the `disabledDays` property. It can be passed a set of modifiers as detailed at http://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/modifiers

The following should do what you need:

```
var twoMonthsAgo = new Date();
twoMonthsAgo.setMonth(twoMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 2);

<DayPicker disabledDays={
{ 
    before: twoMonthsAgo, 
    after: new Date()
}} />
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs, [React Day Picker Modifiers](http://react-day-picker.js.org/docs/api-daypicker.html#modifiers), it looks like you can pass a prop of `fromMonth`, which you can calculate to be the month two months before today's date. You can also pass a `disabledDays` prop that will disable days according to your parameters.

```
const lastMonth = new Date();
lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 2);
<DayPicker
  fromMonth={lastMonth} 
  disabledDays={{ after: today }}
/>
```

You may need to tweak that a bit, but it should show you where to go from.

Comment: fromMonth includes all dates in that month so if today is 20th April, you can select any date from the​ 1st January using your logic

Comment: It sounds like that is what the question is asking for: the dates in a range from two months ago until today.

Comment: update to new version:   " disabled={{ after: today }} hidden={{ after: today }} "